# Convert / Hide values from struct

Tags: go

I have an application that creates a user at the database and returns his information (with struct). and I want to send the user model to the client (response of the web server), without password (or more information that I don't want the client will get).
what the right way to do that? make a "UIUser" struct with the only fields that I want to send the client and convert the original model to this struct? or user interface?

and of course, if you can give me an example to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having view structs is probably a good idea in general, as you don't want to couple the API format to internal representation. Regardless, if you just wanna do this the lazy way and avoid serializing the password, you can always use the `-` json struct tag:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type user struct {
    ID      int     `json:"id"`
    Name    string  `json:"name"`
    Pass    string  `json:"-"`
}

func main() {
    u := &user{123, "John", "supersecret"}
    b, err := json.Marshal(u)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yewtt1lyvzu)

Comment: as also @atayenel recommended me, this is exactly what I wanted, and it works like a magic

Answer (score 2):

I have seen some examples doing what you described. A different struct with just desired data and a transform function between both structs. Depending on your application , it is also possible to make fields private or public. For example, Json or Yaml parser of golang only fills public fields of a struct.

If you are coming from a more OOP background, you can always write Getter-Setter methods to your struct.

Easiest method seems to be the one you wrote in your question.

Comment: The problem with getters that I need to call all the getters I want to send the client, and I want to make my life easier just making a UI struct with the data I want to make public. I will check about your first suggestion, sounds right